# Binding click event handlers in a loop causing problems in jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops, closures, onclick

I am trying to run the following code:

I pass parameter to a function, but it always has the value of the last object run through the loop. I read some articles about it on stackoverflow, but I couldn't find out how to make it run in my solution.

The object is a JSON object returned from the server. All it's values are correct.

```
for(var i = 0;i<parents.length;i++){
            var row        = $(document.createElement("tr"));
            var colName    = $(document.createElement("td"));

            var aDisplayCol = $(document.createElement("a"));

            var parentId = parents[i]['PARENT_ID'];

            aDisplayCol.attr("href","#").html(parents[i]['NAME']);
            aDisplayCol.bind('click',function(){ alert(parentId);});


            colName.append(aDisplayCol);

            row.append(colName);
            $('#pages tbody').append(row);
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a scope problem. By the time the event handler function is executed, the value of `parentId` has changed and is not longer what you expected.

This can be solved making the original event handler function be returned by another function which, in turn, is passed the value of `parentId` as argument:

```
function getEventHandlerFunction(id){
    return function() {
        alert(id);  // variable found in the closure with the expected value
    };
}


aDisplayCol.bind('click', getEventHandlerFunction(parentId));
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there's a problem with using `parentId` in the callback.

Try `alert(parents[i]['PARENT_ID']);`.

**EDIT:** Let's see if we can get around our scope issues with [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

```
aDisplayCol.data("parentId",parents[i]['PARENT_ID']);
aDisplayCol.click(function() {
   alert($(this).data('parentId'));
});
```

Comment: Nope, that's not causing it. Actually, I discovered yesterday that the .click function can't handle the following: 

aDisplayCol.click(function(){ whatever(target,dest, parents[i]['PARENT_ID']); return false; });

I assume it is a bug. Passing a variable instead works fine.

Comment: Nah I don't think it's a bug. I think it's a scope issue. I don't think `i` exists within the scope of the click handler.

Comment: you forgot to close the parenthesis at .data

Comment: using .data worked! AWESOME :D thanks. It is a closure problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the clouseres problems with the eventData parameter of the bind function
like this

```
var message = 'Spoon!';
$('#foo').bind('click', {msg: message}, function(event) {
    alert(event.data.msg);
});
message = 'Not in the face!';
$('#bar').bind('click', {msg: message}, function(event) {
    alert(event.data.msg);
});
```

this is from the jquery bind api documentation http://api.jquery.com/bind/#passing-event-data