# JQuery binding in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    outPut.innerHTML += "<div id='file" + i + "'>" + i + "</div>";
    $('#file' + i).on('click', function(event) {
        alert('User clicked on ' + i);
    }).css('cursor', 'pointer');
}
```

and only last element gets event attached. What is the problem?

See the test here http://jsfiddle.net/haF7Y/

Comment: ... or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531386/binding-click-event-handlers-in-a-loop-causing-problems-in-jquery or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774636/jquery-event-handler-created-in-loop

Comment: OMG, dont do that... use a class and/or data attribute and bind once... Why bind `n` different functions that do the same thing!?

Comment: If you're wondering why you've been downvoted, it's apparently due to the percieved lack of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are missing - event listeners are asynchronous in nature! So always use a closure function inside the loop when performing such task as this! See below -

```
for (i = 0; i <10; i++){
  (function(i){
    outPut.innerHTML +="<div id='file"+ i + "'>" + i+ "</div>";
    $('#file' + i).on('click', function(event) {
      alert('User clicked on ' + i);
    }).css('cursor', 'pointer');
  }(i))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the click event from the `for loop`.

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^=file]', function(e){
    alert('user clicked on '+ this.id.split('file')[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

work with jquery objects like this (and create a closure)

```
var jOutPut = $('div:first');

var create = function(i) {
    var j = $('<div/>')
        .attr('id', 'file' + i)
        .css('cursor', 'pointer')
        .html(i)
        .click(function(event){
            alert('User clicked on ' + i);
        });

    jOutPut.append(j);
}

for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
    create(i);
}
```

Comment: @Matt try again... sorry

Comment: @Matt and @JanDvorak ...  `never post untested code` ... now!

Comment: If I post untested code to demonstrate an algorithm, I mark it as such: "Something along the lines of", "here's a sketch of the solution"... Note that this won't work when _fixing_ someone's code, and it's always a good idea to debug later on :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code should be written:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var newEl = $("<div class='file' data-index='"+i+"'>" + i + "</div>").css('cursor', 'pointer');
    outPut.append(newEl);
}

$('.file').click(function(event) {
        alert('User clicked on ' + $(this).attr('data-index'));
});
```

And here is a fiddle to show it works: http://jsfiddle.net/qX8RQ/

Comment: Revised, sorry I missed the "i". Whats up with all the damn downvotes? You should appreciate the help.

Comment: Not sure `index()` is the best approach. Indexing within some collection would likely be better.

Comment: The downvotes typically signify the answer is factually incorrect or otherwise harmful. You didn't fix the issue. Hence, factually incorrect.

Comment: There are numerous ways to show the index, if you want a more defined index use a "data-index" or "data-___" to store information.

Comment: `data-index` is innovative. +1 for creativity :-)